# Restricting comments in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to lock a Word document (2010 or 2013), such that comments cannot be embedded?  I am looking for the inverse of the option under document protection to restrict editing so that ONLY comments can be included.  I would like to permit all forms of editing OTHER THAN embedded comments.